# 'Invalid Key' error from Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko

I'm trying to set up Fabric for deploying my Python web application and Paramiko is barfing on my private RSA key.  I had been using my key successfully for 6 months, so I know it's good.  In case having a passphrase was the problem, I just made a new key with no passphrase and still get the error.  Help?

Comment: Pastebin of my environment/error:
http://pastebin.com/dd0987d

Comment: The pastebin has expired. Could you you edit the question to add the error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you but here's how I set my SSH user/key in fabric.

```
env.user = "username"
env.key_filename = "/path/to/ssh/keyfile"
```

And it seems to work fine.